# JMeter XPath validator using contains argument

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I'm trying to use the XPath validator in Apache JMeter 5.4 to extract a value and test a JSF application that uses state but I'm having some trouble.

Below is an example of the XML I get back in the response. In the XML I need to return the ViewState value **3760920573413511484:4790185202922842747**. However the id **j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0** isn't always the same in every response (e.g. 'j_id1' could be 'j_id2') and can change, therefore I need the XPath to query when the id contains **javax.faces.ViewState** and for it to return the ViewState value.

I hope that is enough detail. I did check to see if this was answered elsewhere but I couldn't see anything regarding using 'contains'. Thanks in advance.

```
<partial-response>
    <changes>
        <update id="uploadForm:globalMessages">
            <![CDATA[<div id="uploadForm:globalMessages" class="ui-messages ui-widget" aria-live="polite"></div>]]>
        </update>
        <update id="uploadForm:messages">
            <![CDATA[<div id="uploadForm:messages" class="ui-messages ui-messages-noicon ui-widget" aria-live="polite"></div>]]>
        </update>
        <update id="uploadForm:uploadPanel">
            <![CDATA[<div id="uploadForm:uploadPanel" class="ui-outputpanel ui-widget"></div>]]>
        </update>
        <update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0">
            <![CDATA[3760920573413511484:4790185202922842747]]>
        </update>
    </changes>
</partial-response>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath comes with [contains() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) so you can do a partial match on an attribute value like:

```
//update[contains(@id, 'ViewState')]
```

Demo:

[image]

Just in case, consider migrating to [XPath2 Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath2_Extractor) (if not yet), its more powerful and acts faster than XPath Extractor, see [The JMeter XPath2 Extractor: How to Achieve Better Correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-xpath2-extractor-how-to-achieve-better-correlations) article for more details.